# How to get JSON output from sql server 2016

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create a JSON file from sql server 2016 (Tsql). The desired output should be something like below

```
[{

   "name": "xxxx",
    "data": [
        ["Col1Name", Col1Value],
        ["Col2Name", Col2Value],
        ["Col3Name", Col3Value],
        ["Col4Name", Col4Value],
        ["Col5Name", Col5Value],
    ]
}]
```

or it can be something like

```
{
   "name": "xxxxxx",
   "data": [Col1Value, Col2Value, Col3Value, Col4Value, Col5Value]
}
```

I tried few sql queries using **JSON AUTO** and **JSON PATH** as shown below but none of them gets me the desired output. Any help is highly appreciable.

```
SELECT f.name,
data.OneMonth,
data.ThreeMonth, 
data.YTD,
data.OneYear,
data.ThreeYear,
data.FiveYear,
data.TenYear,
data.SinceIncept
FROM dbo.Fund f
JOIN dbo.FundPerf data on   f.FundId = sc.FundId
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with a simple query. You can always use a stored procedure and `JSON_MODIFY`:

```
create table #temp (name varchar(30), col1 varchar(30), col2 varchar(30))
insert into #temp values ('Jason', 'hello', 'world'), ('yeshwanth', 'goodbye', 'world')

create or alter procedure sp_get_json @json varchar(max) out as
begin
  set @json = '[]'

  declare @name varchar(30), @col1 varchar(30), @col2 varchar(30), @item varchar(max)
  declare c cursor for select name, col1, col2 from #temp
  open c
  fetch c into @name, @col1, @col2
  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin
    set @item = JSON_MODIFY('{}', '$.name', @name)
    set @item = JSON_MODIFY(@item, '$.data', JSON_QUERY('[]'))
    set @item = JSON_MODIFY(@item, 'append $.data', @col1)
    set @item = JSON_MODIFY(@item, 'append $.data', @col2)
    set @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(@item))
    fetch c into @name, @col1, @col2
  end
  close c
  deallocate c
end

declare @j varchar(max)
exec sp_get_json @json = @j out
print @j
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the logic. It satisfies my requirement 2. Meanwhile also searching for the requirement 1 since the json file would have more readability.

Comment: Can you expand it further to add column name(s) with the values     [
  {
    "name": "Jason",
    "data": [
      ["col1","hello"],
      ["col2","world"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "yeshwanth",
    "data": [
      ["col1","goodbye"],
      ["col2","world"]
    ]
  }
]

Comment: @yeshwanththummala I'm not sure what you're asking... If you want data to be an array of arrays with 'name', 'value' being elements of the inner arrays, you should use another variable like `set @element = JSON_QUERY('[]')` and `JSON_MODIFY(@element, 'append $', 'col1')` and `JSON_MODIFY(@element, 'append $', 'hello'')`, Then use `set @item = JSON_MODIFY($item, 'append $data', @element)` to append that array to the data array....

Comment: That makes sense to me. I am able to append the inner array. But i am getting the output as "data":[[\"col1\",\"hello\"]","[\"col2\",\"world\"]]}. How can i remove those "\" ?

Comment: Wrap it in a `JSON_QUERY` to be treated as JSON, otherwise it adds it as a string.  Ran into that putting the sample together :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (name varchar(10), Col1Name VARCHAR(10),Col2Name VARCHAR(10),Col3Name VARCHAR(10),Col4Name VARCHAR(10),Col5Name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('xxx', 'Col1Value','Col2Value','Col3Value','Col4Value','Col5Value')

SELECT name
, Col1Name as 'data.Col1Name'
, Col2Name as 'data.Col2Name' 
, Col3Name as 'data.Col3Name' 
, Col4Name as 'data.Col4Name' 
, Col4Name as 'data.Col5Name' 
FROM @Table
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "name":"xxx",
      "data":{
         "Col1Name":"Col1Value",
         "Col2Name":"Col2Value",
         "Col3Name":"Col3Value",
         "Col4Name":"Col4Value",
         "Col5Name":"Col4Value"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If you take another look at my requirement, I need something like an array with comma separated between ColumnName and Columnvalue. i.e., [Col1Name, Col1Value].